# Beacon scans not consistent

Tags: android, ibeacon, ibeacon-android, android-ibeacon

I am using radius networks iBeacon Api. I am scanning the beacons in background mode for every sec.I have two beacons. Some times Scanning the beacons are not consistent. How do I over come this issue?

Assume that there are two beacons

At first Interval Scan

Beacon 1,Beacon 2 Found

At Second Interval Scan

Only Beacon 1 or Beacon 2 coming

At third Interval Scan

Beacon 1 and Beacon2 Found

At fourth Interval

Again Single Beacon coming..

Like this I am getting

Comment: need to describe it properly, "not consistent" meaning? did you check the frequency and-or RSSI signal, it also depends on at what frequency does the beacon emit data

Comment: I have updated the question..Please see this

Comment: also depends on at what frequency does the beacon emit data

Answer (score 3):

The most likely explanation is the beacon you are using is not transmitting frequently enough.  For best performance, a beacon should send out an advertisement at least 10 times per second.  An iOS device acting as an iBeacon sends out advertisements 30 times per second.

When ranging for beacons, the Android iBeacon Library sends updates by default every 1100ms with a list of each beacon discovered in this period.  If no transmissions are detected in this interval for a particular beacon, that beacon will not be included in the list for that scan interval.

Changing your hardware is not necessary to address cases where beacons intermittently are not included in callbacks.  Just maintain a list in software of beacons seen in the last five seconds or so.

Alternately, you may also simply lengthen the scan period, but this will reduce the frequency in which you gat callbacks:

```
iBeaconManager.setBackgroundScanPeriod(5000l); // 5 secs      
iBeaconManager.setForegroundScanPeriod(5000l); // 5 secs
iBeaconManager.updateScanIntervals();
```

Comment: is updateScanIntervals() available for Pro version only?

Comment: It is available in the latest version and of the open source library as well as the pro version. See: https://github.com/RadiusNetworks/android-ibeacon-service/blob/master/src/main/java/com/radiusnetworks/ibeacon/IBeaconManager.java

Answer (score 1):

It is normal case.

Beacon interval is inconsistency, because of multi-path effect.

Every wireless signal has a multi-path effect.

Refer to below link :

- [Multipath propagation on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multipath_propagation)

So, it is impossible to estimate the time when the signal arrived to your smartphone.

If you want to monitor your beacon signal, this app can useful for you.

- [BeaconBox app on Google Play Store](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.nemustech.beaconbox)

See the graph view of your beacon using this app.

It is the fastest way to know how your beacons operate.